# calculate mediane with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that prints numbers in loops.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 80 $i`
do
    for  j in `seq 1 $4`
    do
        ./sujet1 $1 $2 $i  
    done
done
```

`./sujet1 $1 $2 $i` is a C compiled program which prints a number ( but I don't like to print it on screen).

I would like to calculate the mediane of numbers in the second loop that `./sujet1 $1 $2 $i` prints then print this mediane on the screen.
so I'll have `$i` mediane at the end.

I konw I should firstly use `./sujet1 $1 $2 $i >> mediane.txt` to save values. But I don't know how to recover them in the file, calculate mediane, erase them when finishing every loop..

EDIT:

I tried with *awk* as told in comment, but I find it difficult to understand for me

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 80 $i`


do

    for  j in `seq 1 $4`
    do
    awk '{ total += ./sujet1 $1 $2 $i } END { print total/NR }' mediane.txt
    done
done
```

It doesn't work for me.

EDIT 2: for exemple i type ./run.sh 30 40 90 3
so I'll have

```
//for($3= 80 )
2,3   
3,5
4,4
//for($3= 81 )
4,5
1,3
5,6
...
//for($3=90)
2,4
3,5
5,4
```

You notice here for every value in $3 I have $4 value repeating. I want to calculate the median of these $4 values and print one value

Comment: I can't get how to apply this  command in my case..

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you put some simple numbers in and show what it is supposed to do please?

Comment: It sounds like you mean _average_ when you say _mediane_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand, but I think you want to run the `sujet` program lots of times and average the answer.

```
for i in `seq 80 $i`
do
    for  j in `seq 1 $4`
    do
        ./sujet1 $1 $2 $i  
    done
done | awk '{total += $0} END{ print total/NR}'
```

Maybe you want the median of all the outputs of the `sujet` program. If so, pipe the output through `sort` first and then find the middle one with `awk` something like this:

```
for ...
   for ...
      ./sujet ...
   done
done | sort -n | awk '{x[NR]=$0} END{middle=int(NR/2); print x[middle]}'
```

Comment: I don't get any value..  to do it otherwise I want to: 1) save the C programe value in a file. 2) read this value into a variable "total" 3) do 1 & 2 $4 times then calculate the media so devide "total" by $4 ( total is a float ).  I think it's the simpliest way. but I could not code it correctly..

Comment: @infodev Sorry. I still cannot understand you. Have you written the C program? Or is that the problem?

Comment: the C program just prints a float number which changes a little bit every loop turn, and I just want to calculate the median of these numbers at the end of every this second loop

Comment: Maybe you need to move my `| sort -n | awk ...` up one line and put it after the first line containing `done` and not after the second `done`

Answer (score 0):

You could yse 'backticks' operator:

```
result="`./sujet1 $1 $2 $i`"
```

It is used to "inline" run an os command, and to assign it's output to the left-side variable